# Join two tables when the values in two columns don't match

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1:

```
onode_c, dnode_c, dist1
```

Table 2:

```
onode_c, dnode_c, dist2
```

I need a query which returns

```
onode_c, dnode_c, dist1, dist2
```

for the records where `dist1` and `dist2` are not matching in Table 1 and Table 2

```
select  a.onode_c, a.dnode_c, trunc(a.dist1), trunc(b.dist2)
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.onode_c = b.onode_c and a.dnode_c = b.dnode_c and trunc(a.dist1) != trunc(b.dist2);
```

The above query returns the same records multiple times.

Comment: `trunc(b.f1)` ?? I don't see column `f1` in table2. Also `dist` column...

Comment: sorry, 'trunc(a.dist), trunc(b.f1)' should be trunc(a.dist1), trunc(b.dist2)-missed this while modifying the original query to make it simple.

Comment: Is `(onode_c, dnode_c)` a unique or primary key on one or both tables? If just one, which one? I would assume the pair `(onode_c, dnode_c)` is not unique on at least one table since you are reporting multiple rows. And what do you want if, for a given value of `(onode_c, dnode_c)` in a table, there are multiple values in the other table, where `trunc(a.dist) != trunc(b.dist2)` is true for some rows but false for others. Should that value for the node pair be included at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try below statement :

```
select a.onode_c, a.dnode_c, trunc(a.dist), trunc(b.dist2) from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.onode_c = b.onode_c and a.dnode_c = b.dnode_c
where trunc(a.dist1) != trunc(b.dist2);
```

Comment: The table posted in question doesn't have `f1` and `dist` columns

Comment: @IswantoSan then how does OP say the above query returns the same records multiple times????

Comment: I just edited the question based on OP comments...you should fix your answer too..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SELECT DISTINCT` perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  DISTINCT a.onode_c, a.dnode_c, trunc(a.dist1), trunc(b.dist2)
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.onode_c = b.onode_c and a.dnode_c = b.dnode_c and trunc(a.dist1) != trunc(b.dist2);
```